# How can I upload a csv file located in my downloads folder with cypress?

Tags: csv, testing, file-upload, automation, cypress

I have a test that downloads a file after clicking a button, which is saved in my download folder. I need to upload that same file on another screen.

I have this code:

```
const fileName = 'QATest_1.csv'

cy.readFile('C:\\Users\\victo\\Downloads\\QATest_1.csv').then(function (fileContent) {
cy.get('[name="csv"]').attachFile({ fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'application/csv' });

cy.get('[ng-click="subirCsv()"]').click();

});
```

I am getting this error:

`filePath` is not valid.
Please look into docs to find supported `filePath` values

Answer (score 1):

It has finally worked, with this piece of code:

```
const fileName = 'QATest_1.csv';

cy.readFile('C:/Users/victo/Downloads/QATest_1.csv').then(function (fileContent) {

    cy.get('[name="csv"]').attachFile({ fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'application/csv' })

    cy.get('[ng-click="subirCsv()"]').click()

})
```

NOTE: I updated cypress to the latest version and installed the latest version of the 'cyprees-file-upload' plugin

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one

```
cy.uploadPdfFile('[data-cy="file-input"]', 'QATest_1.csv');


Cypress.Commands.add('uploadCSVFile', (selector, fileName) => {
cy.fixture(fileName).then((fileContent) => {
    cy.get(selector).upload({ fileContent, fileName, mimeType:'application/csv' }, { subjectType: 'input' });
});
```

});

Comment: cy.uploadPDfFile is not a function

:(

Comment: yes right, put this method `uploadPDfFile` inside `/support/command.js`

Comment: I'm getting this:

A fixture file could not be found at any of the following paths:

 > cypress\fixtures\QATest_1.csv
 > cypress\fixtures\QATest_1.csv{{extension}}

Comment: I forgot to mention that you have to install this plugin ["cypress-file-upload"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload) not sure that after the error with fixture will disappear but let's try first install the plugin 
and what is {{extension}} mean?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

you can try `cypress-file-upload` https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload module
and you should be able to do it

```
cy.get('[data-cy="file-input"]').attachFile(yourDownloadFolderPath, { force: true });
```

Comment: I'm getting this Error:

A fixture file could not be found at any of the following paths:

 > cypress\fixtures\C:\Users\victo\Downloads\QATest_1.csv